# Abu Dhabi to Bangalore via Kuwait, do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, kuwait

Does an Indian passport holder travelling from Abu Dhabi to Bangalore via Kuwait, with a layover in Kuwait of 6 hours, require a transit visa if not intending to go  out from the airport?

Comment: Is this a self-transfer or is it one ticket (one PNR)?